# How to make the array numbers a value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

How to make the 0 =>, 1 => 2 => a "marketplace_name" value

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Amazon' (length=6)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'amazon-20' (length=9)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#000000' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#000000' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#eeee22' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#caa75b' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/amazon-icon-1.png' (length=79)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'BCF' (length=3)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'ebay-30' (length=7)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#81d742' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/bcf.png' (length=69)
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Macpac' (length=6)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'Macpac-10' (length=9)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#ffffff' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/macpac.png' (length=72)
```

something like this, I want it to be like below so that I can call those marketplaces so that I can use its elements on a particular marketplace.

```
array (size=4)
  Amazon => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Amazon' (length=6)
    ...
  BCF => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'BCF' (length=3)
    ...
  Macpac => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Macpac' (length=6)
    ...
```

Comment: Have you made any efforts yourself so far?

Comment: I am trying different things, currently this on array_merge()

Comment: I think i got it with array_combine()

Answer (score 0):

Associative array maybe helps you:

```
   $amazon= array('marketplace_name' =>  'Amazon','marketplace_affiliate_code' => 'amazon-20'.... so on....);
 $bfg= array('marketplace_name' =>  'bfc','marketplace_affiliate_code' => 'ebay-30'.... so on....);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Hope it helps you.

```
$data = array(
    array(    
        'marketplace_name' => 'Amazon',
        'marketplace_affiliate_code' => 'amazon-20'
    ),
    array(    
        'marketplace_name' => 'BCF',
        'marketplace_affiliate_code' => 'ebay-30'
    ),
    array(    
        'marketplace_name' => 'Macpac',
        'marketplace_affiliate_code' => 'Macpac-10'
    )
);

foreach( $data as $index => $datum ) {
    $marketplace_name = $datum['marketplace_name'];
    unset( $data[ $index ] );
    $data[ $marketplace_name ] = $datum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
$marketplace_list_button_styles = get_field('marketplace_list', option);

foreach ($marketplace_list_button_styles as $style) {
    $mp[] = $style['marketplace_name'];
}

$final_array = array_combine($mp, $marketplace_list_button_styles);

var_dump($final_array);
```

so now it looks like this

```
array (size=4)
  'Amazon' => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Amazon' (length=6)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'amazon-20' (length=9)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#000000' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#000000' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#eeee22' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#caa75b' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/amazon-icon-1.png' (length=79)
  'BCF' => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'BCF' (length=3)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'ebay-30' (length=7)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#004b8d' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#81d742' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/bcf.png' (length=69)
  'Macpac' => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Macpac' (length=6)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'Macpac-10' (length=9)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#ef491f' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#ffffff' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/macpac.png' (length=72)
  'Tent World' => 
    array (size=7)
      'marketplace_name' => string 'Tent World' (length=10)
      'marketplace_affiliate_code' => string 'tent-20' (length=7)
      'button_line_colour' => string '#004117' (length=7)
      'button_text_colour' => string '#004117' (length=7)
      'button_background_colour' => string '#004117' (length=7)
      'button_text' => string '#ffffff' (length=7)
      'button_logo' => string 'http://localhost/website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tentworld.png' (length=75)
```